# Sharepoint Designer stores content & metadata in Database, or on files

Tags: database, sharepoint, metadata, sharepoint-designer

I m working in SharePoint 2013, and m new to it. So can anyone tell me that where does the SPD stores its content and metadata whether in database or in the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lists and contents are stored in the database, and the files are stored in the document library. Control templates files are stored in layout folder.